# UDEV tty Rules with dialog msgbox

Tags: udev, dialog

I'm trying to run a script that open dialog --msgbox when a USB device is connected

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/date >> /tmp/udev.log
/usr/bin/dialog --title "Hello" --msgbox 'Hello world!' 6 20
```

this is my rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SYMLINK+="COM2", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/trigger2.sh"
```

when I connect the device and use

```
cat /tmp/udev.log
```

I can see the device connection time printed but no msgbox
what I'm missing?